# I'm having an issue with a Regular Expression negative lookbehind assertion

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

My regular expression matched test strings.  I was expecting the regular expression not to match the test strings.

Here is my regular expression with a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!Cancels|Amends)\s*F\s*\.\sE\s*\.\sR\s*\.\sC\s*\.\s*No\s*\.\s*2\s*\.\s*[0-9]+\s*\.\s*[0-9]+
```

Here are the strings I'm using the test my regular expression:

```
Cancels F.E.R.C. No. 2.3.0

Amends F.E.R.C. No. 2.0.0
```

I expected the regular expression to not find matches, since the test strings are prefixed with either 'Cancels' or 'Amends'.  However, I am getting these matches:

```
F.E.R.C. No. 2.3.0

F.E.R.C. No. 2.0.0
```

'Cancels ' and 'Amends ' are not being matched (notice the ' ' after 'Cancels' and 'Amends' in the unmatched part of the strings.

If I change the regular expression to have a `\s+` instead of `\s*` right after the negative lookbehind, then I don't get any matches.

```
(?<!Cancels|Amends)\s+F\s*\.\sE\s*\.\sR\s*\.\sC\s*\.\s*No\s*\.\s*2\s*\.\s*[0-9]+\s*\.\s*[0-9]+
```

My question is:

Why is the regular expression getting a match with a `\s*` right after the negative lookbehind but not with a `\s+` right after the negative lookbehind?

Comment: Most regexp engines require lookbehinds to be fixed-size. So you can't have alternatives that are different lengths.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will eventually use the python re package to apply the regular expressions on strings stripped from pdfs via the PyyPDF2 package.  The text stripped from PDFs have a lot of random spaces, thus all of the \s* in the regex's.  For now, I'm just testing the regex's on strings at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Never mind, if this were the problem regex101 would tell you there's an error in the regexp.

Comment: Why are you doubling the backslashes in `\\s`?

Comment: The reason it matches is because `\s*` can match zero spaces. When it matches zero spaces, `Cancel` and `Amends` are not before the `F`.

Comment: I tried to include the initial \s* in the lookback.  As you mentioned, that was not supported.  Cancels|Amends is fixed size and seems to be working.  I feel like if I understood why an \s* after the lookback gives a match and \s+ after the lookback does not give a match, I'd understand what's going on.

Comment: You could try grouping the lookbehinds like this: `((?<!Cancels)|(?<!Amends))` but I'm not sure that's what you're after

Comment: Here's the regular expression.  Not sure what happened with those \\ in the post:

(?<!Cancels|Amends)\s*F\s*\.\s*E\s*\.\s*R\s*\.\s*C\s*\.\s*No\s*\.\s*2\s*\.\s*[0-9]+\s*\.\s*[0-9]+

Comment: When I paste that into regex101 and select Python from the Flavor menu it reports the error **A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width**. Did you forget to change the flavor?

Comment: Yes, I did forget to change the flavor.  So, what I'm trying to do won't work anyway.  Ugh, thank you very much.

Comment: The backslash problem seems to be a bug in the new Stacks editor that newbies get.

Comment: The pattern "wants" to succeed and if you use `\s*` there is sucess just in front of `F.E.R.C.` because there is a space. Thus it's not directly preceded by the words. Same with e.g. [`(?<!bar)\s*foo`](https://regex101.com/r/Ut697L/1). If you use `\s+` the lookbehind "works" because it's fired at the position that is preceded by the words. In other words there is no other place available to let the regex succeed.

Comment: You can add another lookbehind [`(?<!Cancels|Amends)(?<!\s)\s*`...](https://regex101.com/r/bpSIfU/1) to force the lookbehind at non-whitespace or e.g. [`(?<!Amends)(?<!Cancels)(?<!\s)\s*`...](https://regex101.com/r/1EGu42/1) (to make it work in Python)